# Conservation of Energy

Tags: calculus, classical-mechanics

[image: question]

Hello, I am trying to solve the following question using conservation of energy. Part (a) is fine, I have compared it with suvat questions and I have got:

$z_{max} = v_0^2sin^2a/2g$

I am struggling with (b).

I have set

$1/2mv_0^2(cos^2a(j)+sin^2a(k)=1/2mv^2+mgz(k)$ by conservation of energy.

Rearranging and integrating I got

$s = (v_0cosa)t(j)+(v_0sina-\sqrt(2gz))t(k)$

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you.

Comment: Please use parentheses when using slashes for division.  In the first equation, it is not clear that $g$ is in the denominator, while in the second equation the $v$'s are in the numerator.  Alternately use \frac {aa}{bb} to get stacked fractions:  $\frac {aa}{bb}$

Answer (score 2):

For the second equation, from conservation you can write $\frac 12 v_0^2=\frac 12 v(t)^2+gz$-you shouldn't have the angles on the left of the second equation.  Now use the fact that $v_y$ is constant to get $v_z(t)$ and integrate.

Comment: can you clarify how I get $v_y(t)$ please?

Comment: I meant $v_z$-there is nothing going on in $y$.  Use $v^2(t)=v_x^2(t)+v_z^2(t)$

Comment: $v_0^2-2gz=v^2(cos^2a(j)+sin^2a(k))$?

Comment: $v^2(t)=v_0^2-2gz=v_y^2+v_z^2(t), (\frac {dz}{dt})^2=v_0^2(1-\sin^2 \alpha)-2gz, \frac {dz}{dt}=\sqrt{v_0^2(1-sin^2 \alpha)-2gz}$

Comment: can you give me pointers? I think I am aiming for $z=v_0t-0.5gt^2$?

Comment: I read $\alpha$ wrong in the last comment, so the $\sin$ should be $\cos$ to get the horizontal velocity.  You are now looking for $z=v_0\sin \alpha t-\frac 12gt^2$.  The differential equation is separable, so you are integrating $\frac {dz}{\sqrt {v_0^2\sin^2 \alpha-2gz}}=dt$

Comment: How would you solve the above differential equation? I understand that you have separate variables but I can't seem to get to $z=v_0\sin(\alpha)t-\frac{1}{2}gt^2$.

Comment: What are the limits supposed to be on the integral?

Comment: You do both sides as indefinite integrals, then assess the constant with your initial condition of $z=0$ when $t=0$